# KeyListener code for "<" and ">"

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm using KeyListener for my project and I don't find the adequate code for the chevrons "<" and ">".

I supposed that this is with the form "VK_ENTER" ( code used for the ENTER key ).

Thank you !

Comment: [VK_LESS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_LESS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyEvent.VK_LESS

KeyEvent.VK_GREATER

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer ! :D

Comment: Sorry for my review .